# How to add an fa-icon to a custom menu?

Tags: menu

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu/) but still tried to add a custom icon to a custom admin menu with an extension

```
_custommenu_civix_insert_navigation_menu($menu, 'Docuthèque', [
    'label' => 'Dossier formation FC PSE1',
    'name' => 'Dossier formation FC PSE1',
    'url' => 'https://ffmns.gestad.net/documents/2022/11/dossier-fc-pse1.xlsx/',
    'permission' => 'access CiviCRM',
    'attr' => ['target' => '_blank'],
    'icon' => 'crm-i fa-file-spreadsheet'
  ]);
```

It doesn't work but can you confirm that this is really not possible?

Comment: Can you include the custom code params?

Comment: edited. The menu works, just the icon doesn't show up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there isn't any icon with 'fa-file-spreadsheet' in Civi. Can you check in the New Activity type form if the one you are looking for is present or the one you can select from the list?

Hover on one of the icons, it should display the icon text which you can use in the code. For example, I would replace `fa-file-spreadsheet` with `fa-plus-square-o` from the screenshot below.

Or you can use the list from [Font-Awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4/icons/).

Based on your code example I would use `'crm-i fa-file-excel-o'`

HTH

Pradeep

[image]

Comment: OMG, that was so obvious, thanks Pradeep!

Comment: 'icon' => 'crm-i fa-file-excel-o' works like a charm :-)